# How to create a selectMode()

Tags: java

I created a method called selectMode(); and I want that method to be able to select a different mode while running. For example I have to different displays but only one display will show and if I want to access the other display I want to be able to select it.

Comment: Your question is really vague. Some more details and/or code would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just add an argument to it:

```
selectMode( mode );
```

And either always require that `mode` be supplied, or create a second overload of `selectMode` with the argument.